# css ladda's like animation in WPF

Tags: c#, css, wpf, animation

I'm starting with c#(wpf), I come from web development and there is a css library that has some nice effects for buttons, this is the demo page:

[Ladda](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/)

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the 'contract' effect in **WPF** with an story board or some kind of animation, basically the target is to transform a button(any size) into a circular button, fade out a label and fade in an image, all at the same time, I was thinking in a user control like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
                <loader:LoadingControl></loader:LoadingControl>
                <TextBlock Text="Hola" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

But I really don't know how to do it, any ideas?

---

Here are some images of the desired effect, if you don't want to open the link I provided:)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

And back.